# Naccess installation error in fortran 77 compilation

Tags: fortran, gfortran

While trying to install naccess(software) I encountered an error relating to fortran compilation "non-negative width required in format string.I am trying to compile it on the terminal of ubuntu. The error produced by using the command necessary to install (`csh install.scr`) is the following:

```
installing naccess in directory /home/zeynep/Downloads/naccess2.1.1
created naccess - cshell script
compiling accall.f
accall.f:255:31:

write(4,'(a,i)')
            1
Error: Nonnegative width required in format string at (1)
```

Comment: You will have to correct the code. There is no gfortran option to allow just `i` there instead of `i0`.